# htmlescape converting some unicode characters

Tags: html, perl, unicode, escaping

I have an issue here where  i am using perl to input some characters through an input textbox and save into database. All the values will go through a function to run escapeHTML before saving into the database. Problem is this escapeHTML function is converting some of my Chinese characters to HTML code as well which is shown in Example 2 and 3. I'm just wondering why is escapeHTML only impacting some unicode characters and not all ??

Hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks

```
use CGI qw(escapeHTML);

$string = "泰国";
$string = escapeHTML($string);

$string2 = "مرحبا بالعالم";
$string2 = escapeHTML($string2);

example 1: 
$VAR1 = 'Dump out string مرحبا بالعالم';
$VAR1 = 'Dump out after escapeHTML string مرحبا بالعالم';

Example 2: 
$VAR1 = 'Dump out string 泰国';
$VAR1 = 'Dump out after escapeHTML string 泰▒&#8250;▒';

Example 3:
$VAR1 = 'Dump out string 泰国 - <font>TEST</font>';
$VAR1 = 'Dump out after escapeHTML string 泰▒&#8250;▒ - &lt;font&gt;TEST&lt;/font&gt;';
```

Comment: Where does escapeHTML come from? Are you using a module, probably with `use Some::Module;` at the top of your script?
The second line has a syntax error: **$**escapeHTML($string) is not valid, probably the $ should be removed.

Comment: sorry i've already ammended my question and yes its from use CGI qw(escapeHTML); i'm a little new to perl and getting use to the syntax. sorry

Comment: if you want to use unicode strings in you source, you need to `use utf8;`. If all your input/outputs  are in utf8, you should probably also `use utf8::all`, which will open all of your file handles in utf8. Otherwise, for legacy reasons, some utf8 strings risk being output as latin1.

Comment: `utf8::all` is remarkably convenient and 95% good ideas.  I prefer the [Standard Preamble from the Perl Unicode Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicook.html#!1e-0%3a-Standard-preamble) as it sets my code free of the [WTF 5%](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/utf8-all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way of HTML encoding is [HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Entities)

Encode only default unsafe chars:

```
$encoded = encode_entities($string);
```

Encode < and >, but no & and others:

```
$encoded = encode_entities($string,'<>');
```

Encode non-plain ASCII:

```
$encoded = encode_entities($input, '^\n\x20-\x25\x27-\x7e');
```

`escapeHTML()` is not part of the [CGI documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI), I assume that it isn't build for being used from outside the CGI module. It's using HTML::Entities itself if you look at the CGI source:

```
$ENCODE_ENTITIES     = q{&<>"'};
sub escapeHTML {
     require HTML::Entities;
     # hack to work around  earlier hacks
     push @_,$_[0] if @_==1 && $_[0] eq 'CGI';
     my ($self,$toencode,$newlinestoo) = CGI::self_or_default(@_);
     return undef unless defined($toencode);
     my $encode_entities = $ENCODE_ENTITIES;
     $encode_entities .= "\012\015" if ( $encode_entities && $newlinestoo );
     return HTML::Entities::encode_entities($toencode,$encode_entities);
}
```

Seeing this sourcecode, I wonder why it does any Unicode encoding at all.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer and i think i know whats the issue here. I actually referred to  this page http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html and there is a section on escapeHTML which states "In addition, the hexadecimal 0x8b and 0x9b characters, which some browsers incorrectly interpret as the left and right angle-bracket characters, are replaced by their numeric character entities ("&#8249" and "&#8250;")". So i guess that is why only some characters were affected by this.